# Checking if an object of a list has some value with drools

Tags: list, object, drools

I have some problems checking if an object of a list has a value with drools.

My model is this

```
class Products{
    private List<Approver> approvalPath;
}
class Approver{
    private String employeeName;
}
```

So, I need to make a rule like this

```
rule "member"
    when
        //approvalPath has an approver with name "Charles" (for example)
    then
        //do something
end
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are two versions.

```
when
  $app: Approver( employeeName == "Charles" )
  Products( approvalPath contains $pp )
```

And:

```
when
  Products( $ap: approvalPath )
  Approver( employeeName == "Charles" ) from $ap
```

Number 1 requires the insertion of Approver objects as facts.

Comment: I have a new question in relation with this. If I want to add an object of type approver to the list, how can I get the index of the element?

For example, I did this

approver : Approver(employeeNumber.equalsIgnoreCase("13684")) from $approvalPath

to get the object. But there's a way to get the index, to add an object to the list after or before?

Comment: Basing something on the index of an element in a list is usually not a good idea. If some order should be maintained, you'll have to design an appropriate container that takes care of inserts "in the right place".

Comment: How can we specify same in decision table ?

Answer (score 2):

```
rule member
when
    $p : Products()
    $a : Approver( name == "Charles" ) from $p.approvalPath
then
...
end
```

The above rule will fire once for each Approver named Charles in the list. If you want to fire the rule just once, no matter how many approvers named Charles are in the list, just wrap the second line in exists( ... ).