# Breaking from inside a collect in Drools

Tags: drools

I'm new to Drools, so I apologize if this is basic. But how do I break in the middle of a `collect`? For example, in the following code

```
 c : Customer()
items : List( size == c.items.size ) 
      from collect( Item( price > 10 ) from c.items )
```

This code checks if all items have a price > 10. But if I want to see if any of the items have a price > 10, what do I do? I can change code to `size > 0` instead of `size == c.items.size`, but that would still mean the collect iterates through all the items. Is it possible to break if any of the items match the condition from within the collect?

Comment: It is answered already here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22257132/checking-if-an-object-of-a-list-has-some-value-with-drools

Comment: @jomarko, the question it the post you have referenced is not quite the same. In that post, OP doesn't want to do any filtering in the properties of the elements of the collection (i.e. does the collection contains a String "ABC"?). In this other case, OP wants to apply a filter to the elements of the collection and then ask for existence (i.e. does the collection contains a String that starts with "A"?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to check for existence, then you can use the `exists` operator:

```
rule "Sample"
  c : Customer()
  exists Item( price > 10 ) from c.items
then
  //...
end
```

In this case, you don't even need to use a `collect`. The `from` keyword will "loop" over all of the items in the collection.

You can check the [Drools' Manual](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/drools-docs/html_single/#_conditional_element_code_exists_code) for more information about this Conditional Element.

Hope it helps,

Comment: Huh, didn't know it was this simple. Thanks.

Comment: Is my original code above for checking if all items satisfy the condition correct? Or is there a simpler way of doing that as well?

Comment: Read about the `forall` conditional element in the documentation.